# Remove specific cards in a deck

Tags: c#

So I made a deck of cards with enums. But now I need to delete all the cards from 2 to 6 in the different suits through a `List<T>`.  This piece of the code is given:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var d = new Deck();
    Log(Converteer.ToString(d), "NIEUWE DEK");
     // this works

   d.RemoveNonManilleCards();
   Log(Converteer.ToString(d, 8), "MANILLE-DECK");
    // should be ->
    // ♠A -  ♠7 -  ♠8 -  ♠9 - ♠10 -  ♠B -  ♠D -  ♠H
    // ♥A -  ♥7 -  ♥8 -  ♥9 - ♥10 -  ♥B -  ♥D -  ♥H
    // ♣A -  ♣7 -  ♣8 -  ♣9 - ♣10 -  ♣B -  ♣D -  ♣H
   // ♦A -  ♦7 -  ♦8 -  ♦9 - ♦10 -  ♦B -  ♦D -  ♦H
```

And this is the deck being created and the void for deleting the cards. But I think I'm doing it completely wrong.

```
public partial class Deck : List<Card>
{
    public Deck()
    {
        MakeDeck();
    }
    protected virtual void MakeDeck()
    {
        foreach (Suit k in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
        {
            foreach (Rank n in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Rank)))
            {
                this.Add(new Card(k, n));
            }
        }
    }

    public void RemoveNonManilleCards()
    {
        foreach (Suit k in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
        {
            foreach (Rank n in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Rank)))
            {
                this.RemoveRange(1, 5);
            }
        }

    }
```

Can some of you point me in the right direction?

Comment: This may not be correct, given that I don't know how your enums look like but why don't you just use LINQ to remove all the cards that have values from 2 to 6? `this.Where(card => c.Rank > 6 && c.Rank < 1);`

Comment: Makes no sense for a RemoveRange in foreach (Rank

Comment: This isn't an answer, so posting as a comment. As a best practice, when removing from a collection by index (List in this case) it is best to iterate thru the collection backwards.  This prevents the collection from 'collapsing' and the indexes just removed being populated again for the next iteration.

Comment: my enums : 

 public enum Suit{ Spades, Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds}
    public enum Rank{ Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King }

Comment: Have you tried _debugging_? It really is a great help to understand what you code is doing and why it is or is not doing what you expect it to do. If you step through your `Remove` loops, you will probably see very quickly what is happening ans why that doesn't work. That should also help finding a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found how to fix the problem

```
public void RemoveNonManilleCards()
{
  for (int index = Count - 1; index >= 0; --index)
  {
    Kaart kaart = this[index];
    if (card.rank>= Rank.Two&& card.Rank<= Rank.Zes)
      this.RemoveAt(index);
  }
```

Thanks for the answers!